React Router not rendering anything on npm start
Does anyone have any ideas why when I run npm start it just shows a blank page? I have tried multiple ways of routing my home page to my component of StorePicker. If I just hardcode the component into create root it works just fine.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './css/style.css';
import StorePicker from './components/StorePicker';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'

const router = createBrowserRouter([{
  path: '/',
  element: <StorePicker />,
}]) 

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('main')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
)

I have tried the old way with BrowserRouter using Routes and Route, same issue.
counsole.log error shows
Uncaught TypeError: R.current is null
useState React
St index.tsx:485
React 7
S scheduler.production.min.js:13
L scheduler.production.min.js:14

When you run npm start do you have open a web browser that is navigated to the URL you are hosting? Are there any errors in the terminal or in the browser console that would indicate any issues? Unfortunately you haven't provided much here for anyone to work with. FWIW I don't see any overt issues in the code you have shared here.

When I run npm start I am using  - Local:    http://localhost:3000

In devtools check the console for error logs and update the question

question has been updated with console log error

yes I have a browser opened to the host.

I have figured it out, react-router-dom was not installed. looked through the json folder and found it missing. Thank you for your time all!

react-router-dom was not installed. looked through json package and found it was not there.
